# Mail merge alternative

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, mail-merge

I have a template Word document which I use when writing supporting technical documents to send with CAD drawings. Due to the nature of the product we create, this accompanying technical note is almost identical for every customer we supply the document to, with specific values different for each customer. For example;

> This document should be read in conjunction with drawing number `XXXXX` and `CUSTOMER_NAME` specification.
>
> The item will be `X`mm in height, `Y`mm in length

For each customer, the varying values will always be the same. Currently, I have written some VBA which gives me a dropdown list on a userform which lists all our exsiting customers. When I choose a customer, the VBA does a simple "find and replace" on specific values (`CUSTOMER_NAME`, `X` and `Y` value etc).

Although this solution works at the moment it is not very scalable and time consuming to edit (easily). It also means if I choose the wrong customer, I need to start again (can't just choose another customer from the list).

I don't want to use a mail merge as I don't want to have to rely on a database in the background, the file should be completely independent.

Does anyone have any examples of other ways this could be done?

Comment: An Excel file can act as being a database (via ODBC) e.g. for mailmerge.

Comment: @Hannu I don't really want to have to rely on any file, I want the Word doc to be completely independent. I'm happy to have the values hard coded - the real issue is creating the "placeholder" for the variables within the document.

Comment: Idea: Try to change your VBA code to use re-use REFERENCES instead of replacing the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have described the use case for my tool Generative Word Variables: http://www.gewova.com/

[image]